# How to reuse routes in Ember 2?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, single-page-application, ember-router

We have fairly complex component - `UserProfile`.

This component has a number of tabs each with multiple tabs on their own.
This results in generating about 20-25 routes for just this component.

Now this component can be visited by multiple routes.

It seems the only way to implement this is to literally copy/paste the routes/templates for UserProfile in every single parent route.

Is it possible to somehow reuse the routes of `UserProfile` across multiple parents?

**Update:**

Sample code.

Here `userdetail` route is child of both `list` and `board`.

Currently we will have to copy/paste the router & template files for `userdetail` under both `list` and `board` folders.

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('list', function() {
    this.route('userdetail',{ path: ':id' });
  });
  this.route('board', function() {
    this.route('userdetail',{ path: ':id' });
  });
});
```

Comment: can you post your route structure ?

Comment: @Bek add sample route

Comment: Why not just name the function and pass that into each route.

Comment: i dont understand you. can you post details in an answer?

Comment: I think you need to nest `board` and `list` inside `userdetail`, or remove `userdetail` route make it component and use queryParam to determine which user to render

Comment: that is not possible. as i said this is sample code. i need to know if a route can be attached to multiple parents. from your comments it looks like that is not possible

Comment: @pdeva what exactly are you trying to achieve. If ur UI is nested ur routes should be nested or If you are just trying to make a url look in a particular way there may better alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible in Ember unfortunately. The only thing you can do to reduce the duplication is to make use of mixins and partials for the duplicated routes/templates/controllers/etc.

I'm also facing this problem several times in apps I'm building and it gets really messy when you have a lot of duplicate child routes.

Comment: Using mixins is the way to go indeed. It's basically duplicating the routes without the actual duplication. The file tree ends up a bit messy though, with all the one-line files around.